# anomaly when overriding bootstrap in django

Tags: css, django

For the past two hours I've been trying to figure out a strange behavior when trying to override bootstrap in Django.

At the beginning, without any custom css file, the result was this:

[image: output without any custom css file]

Then I created a custom css file: `my_site/css/master.css`

```
.index-jumbotron {
  background-color: #006DB0;
}

#main-title {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

It resulted in this:
[image: my_site/css/master.css output]

So far, so good.

But now, if I change anything on that same file (even when putting !important and taking good care of the specificity system), the result is always the same as the image immediately above.

However, when I indicate my template to point to another file `my_site/css/master2.css` or `css/master.css`, indeed the result is as I would have expected:

[image: my_site/css/master2.css output]

I can't get my head around this. Do you have any idea? Do you know if the package django-bootstrap3 could have anything to do with that? I installed it in between my two different version of the custom css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a browser caching issue - did you say 'disable cache' in the developer toolbar (network tab) of your browser? This is usually the easiest solution.

Another option is to open the styles file in your browser and hit 'ctrl+r' to force reload of the css file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually this morning it just started working out of the blue. Maybe the cache expired?